# driver.manage().logs().get("browser"); does not work when called again

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to capture the browser console logs of Chrome using selenium webdriver. I used the below method twice in a `@Test` method. It returns the console logs when it is executed for the first time but when I call it again it returns an empty log entry.

```
public String getConsoleLogs(WebDriver driver)
{
     String consoleError="";
     LogEntries log=driver.manage().logs().get("browser"); 
     for(LogEntry entry:logs.getAll())
            {
                  consoleError+=entry.toString()
             }
     return consoleError;
}
```

Edit: Altered the code to give more clarity on my issue. When this is method is called the second time, the consoleError is an empty String.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the Webdriver Docs:

> Note that log buffers are reset after each call, meaning that available log entries correspond to those entries not yet returned for a given log type. In practice, this means that this call will return the available log entries since the last call, or from the start of the session.

If this doesn't fit your needs, you need to push the logs onto a stack upon reading them so you can refer to them later.

Answer (score 1):

It returns log entries not string. Use the following will solve your issue

```
 for (LogEntry entry : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER)) {
        String msg = entry.getMessage();
        System.err.println("Message: " + msg);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Waqar...My issue is not regarding the return object. Thanks for pointing out about the return type though, I changed my question accordingly. I've already implemented the logic you mentioned. By returning empty string i meant that the log entry was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Return type of `driver.manage().logs().get("browser");` is `LogEntries` not `String`
Just change the it

```
public LogEntries getConsoleLogs(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.manage().logs().get("browser");
}
```

You have get all the log entries and then need to iterate whenever you want

e.g.

```
for (LogEntry entry : getConsoleLogs(driver)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getMessage());
    }
```